# Slightly modify the Camera intent

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I need to slightly modify the default camera intent in android - for example I want to start the camera in **360p** quality, when starting **front camera to be the active one** and to be **oriented in landscape**. I have done a research and find some put extra options that could be used but it seems they do not work properly. So i think that the best way to do this is to find the build in camera intent code and do some modifications.

Where I can find the source of the build in camera intent and also the meta data part in the manifest(if there are some specific options to start the intent)?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to slightly modify the default camera intent in android - for example I want to start the camera in 360p quality, when starting front camera to be the active one and to be oriented in landscape.

I am going to guess that by "default camera intent" you mean an `Intent` for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

> I have done a research and find some put extra options that could be used but it seems they do not work properly.

For `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, there is no extra to force 360p, and not all cameras support that resolution. There is no extra to force a front-facing camera, and not all devices have a front-facing camera. I am skeptical that `EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION` will do what you want, and there is no requirement that any camera app must support `EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION`.

> So i think that the best way to do this is to find the build in camera intent code and do some modifications.

I am going to assume that by "build in camera intent code" you mean "built-in camera app".

> Where I can find the source of the build in camera intent and also the meta data part in the manifest(if there are some specific options to start the intent)?

Few manufacturers ship [the AOSP camera app](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera2/). They replace it with their own. The source code for their own camera apps will be in their offices.